# Please help replace links to non-Stack Imgur images

Tags: discussion, editing, images

Salutations, good StackExchange editors. Over the past few weeks, users (including me) helped to replace Flickr links with Imgur links in Slytherincess's questions, as requested [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/what-to-do-about-flickr). The campaign was successful, and the search query made by Alex for her Flickr-using posts [now returns nothing.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3500+url%3Aflickr.com)

---

Now, however, there are still about:

- [15 posts from other users using Flickr for images in them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aflickr.com/photos);
- [41 posts using images from Blogspot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Abp.blogspot.com);
- [177 Wikia "vignettes"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Avignette);
- [120 Imgur (but non-Stack Imgur) images](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.imgur.com). (lesser priority)

Please help improve the site by replacing these with i.stack.imgur.com links! **Much more importantly, please add image descriptions to make the web a better place for people with disabilities.**

Here's a quick guide as to how to get images from Flickr in Stack's Imgur:

1. Go to the post. Go into editing, and find a link to a URL that looks approximately like `http://www.flickr.com/photos/slytherincess/7089921451/`.
2. Copy the link and put it in a new tab.
3. **On Firefox:** Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
4. **On Chrome:** Right click, choose "View Page Source."
5. Go to line 107 in the source code. Copy the URL in the quotes.
6. Go to SE, make a new dummy question. Insert an image, pasting in the URl.
7. Copy the i.stack.imgur.com link it makes from the bottom of the page, then paste it into the question or answer that used Flickr to replace the link, and you've got one question fixed, preserved for the future web.

With direct links to image files, just paste them into the photo uploader and copy-paste the link.

Comment: What's the point of step 6? You could just add an image onto the target post at the end?

Comment: Re image descriptions: You may find [this Q&A helpful](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11082/36526) for writing those.

Comment: As a side note, part of the problem is that the mobile site directly links images images when you provide a URL instead of doing the imgur thing.

Answer (score -3):

Nope.

What you are proposing is that people mass copy images they may have no idea of who's ownership: that's a big no no.

I didn't check them, but I guess/hope Slytherincess images were all produced and owned by her in first place so that she had all the rights to publish them on Flickr, and thus later being able to move them to Stack Imgur.

The other 353 images you are talking about, well...they must be checked one by one before doing anything with them.

Comment: Whilst a valid point this doesn't mean we shouldn't do this. If anything we should actually check these images to make sure we can even share them here in the first place and if not remove them from the posts all together. And on another point IANAL but from my limited understanding sharing screenshots, which I imagine most of these are, should be fine... I _think_.

Comment: In addition to what @TheLethalCarrot said (and IANAL either), it's always possible to leave a link to the source. In any case (Flickr nonwithstanding), images that are "just" linked as of now don't really respect any ownership either, do they? I mean, they're just put here. Plus how is that really any different that taking a book cover from Goodreads and transporting it into Stack Imgur? I don't follow.

Comment: Images on SE are almost entirely covered by the principle of 'fair use', hence why they're almost never asked (by the rights holders) to be removed